# How do you sudo with xonsh?

Tags: shell, sudo, xonsh

I get the error `xonsh: subprocess mode: permission denied: sudo`.

Comment: Can you run `sudo` successfully when you're *not* using `xonsh`?

Comment: Yes. I also checked that the ownership and rights of my other shells and xonsh match. The only difference is that xonsh is in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in `xonsh`.  In the `build_ins.py` module, `xonsh` attempts to determine if a file is "binary" or not by opening it and reading a few bytes:

```
  def _is_binary(fname, limit=80):
      with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
          for i in range(limit):
              char = f.read(1)
              if char == b'\0':
                  return True
              if char == b'\n':
                  return False
              if char == b'':
                  return False
      return False
```

Security sensitive programs like `sudo` are often executable but not readable, so this blows up.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/larsks/xonsh/commit/fbfea75d49a13cae4f9e86c1d9935228a923c769) is a possible patch for this behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how nobody realized `sudo` doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is that not many people are using `xonsh`.  It's not something I had ever heard of until I saw your question.

Comment: To be clear, sudo does work even with this bug on many systems (which is why it was missed). Some distributions choose to make sudo unreadable-but-executable. This is not categorically true for all Linux distros.  There is a PR into xonsh that fixes this.

Comment: The bug has now been fixed in master. Sorry about the problem in the first place.