# ls ~ permission denied with xonsh in Cygwin

Tags: bash, ls, cygwin, xonsh

I tried to use `xonsh` in my Cygwin terminal, but ran into some problems with permissions:

```
loom@tatooine ~ $ ls
xonsh: subprocess mode: permission denied: ls
```

However, I can use the command `ls` as follows:

```
loom@tatooine ~ $ /usr/bin/ls
Density_201807  apt-cyg  brdmp_999  setup-x86_64.exe  tmp
```

So I tried to find out what `ls` is

```
loom@tatooine ~ $ which ls
ls --color=auto -v
```

I have no problem with `ls` without `xonsh` in native Cygwin terminal:

```
loom@tatooine ~
$ ls
Density_201807  apt-cyg  brdmp_999  setup-x86_64.exe  tmp

loom@tatooine ~
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

So, it looks like there are two different `ls` in `xonsh` case. Is there a command to find out, where `xonsh` have got its  `ls` from? I have tagged question with `xonsh`, but I hope the answer demands only knowledge of bash

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222845/ .

Comment: As `xonsh` is not a cygwin package how did you installed it ?

Comment: The first comment leads to mention of a bug but it was fixed three years ago so barring that being the issue... Looks like `ls` is an alias. I don't know anything about xonsh and whether it handles aliases but in purely bash terms you can run native ls with `\ls` or, worse comes to worst, remove the alias with `unalias ls` (Is `ls` in your PATH?). Shot in the dark.

Comment: @matzeri - I installed xonsh to cygwin with `pip3 install xonsh`